# SAS 9.4 bar chart with goups and subgroups

Tags: sas

i trie to make a bar chart with groups and subgroups.
so far i got a stucked barchart like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVclo.png)

the code as follows:

```
proc sgpanel data=transp_4;
panelby time / layout=columnlattice onepanel
colheaderpos=bottom rows=2 novarname noborder;
vbar type / group=grupp_text response=col1 stat=sum group=time   
nostatlabel;
colaxis display=(nolabel);
rowaxis grid;
run;
```

but i want the bars to be next to each other and not stucked.
any ideas?
thanks,
sandra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `groupdisplay=cluster` option to change it from stacked to grouped.

```
proc sgpanel data=transp_4;
    panelby time / layout=columnlattice onepanel
        colheaderpos=bottom rows=2 novarname noborder;
    vbar type / group=grupp_text response=col1 stat=sum group=time   
        nostatlabel
        groupdisplay=cluster;
    colaxis display=(nolabel);
    rowaxis grid;
run;
```